# MySQL query to return MIN() and MAX() of different columns for multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I currently have a prices table with the following layout:

```
id    codename    price    discount     timestamp
1     1234        599      50           2015-06-10 00:00:00
2     1234        1099     25           2015-06-11 00:00:00
3     3344        199      33           2015-06-12 00:00:00
4     5565        2499     0            2015-06-13 00:00:00
5     5565        1299     50           2015-06-14 00:00:00
```

I need an SQL query that will give me a single row for each codename. Each row must contain the codename, then the lowest price (along with the associated discount and timestamp for that price), as well as the latest timestamp (again with the associated price and discount for that timestamp)

Desired output:

```
codename  minTimePrice  minTimeDis  minTime              latestPrice  latestPriceDis  latestPriceTime
1234      599           50          2015-06-10 00:00:00  1099         25              2015-06-11 00:00:00
3344      199           33          2015-06-12 00:00:00  199          33              2015-06-12 00:00:00
5565      1299          50          2015-06-14 00:00:00  1299         50              2015-06-14 00:00:00
```

EDIT: So I have gotten to where I can have the 2 seperate queries, one gets the row with the MIN(price) and the second gets the row with the MAX(timestamp) for each codename.

Now what I need to do is join them together so that they are all on the same row (grouped by codename) as in the example above.

[SQL Fiddle of 2 queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3873/20)

Comment: can you give sqlfiddle link please

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
Select codename, minPrice, minDis, minTime, latestPrice, latestDis,  latestTime  from 
(
    Select T_Low.codename, minPrice, minDis, minTime, T_Latest.latestPrice, T_Latest.latestDis,  T_Latest.latestTime from
    (
        select * from (
    select row_number() over(partition by codename order by codename, price) row_id, codename, price as minPrice, discount as minDis, timestamp as minTime from 
        (
        select codename, discount, timestamp , min(price) as price from prices 
        group by codename, discount, timestamp
        )T
        ) T1 
        where row_id = 1
    ) T_Low
    left join 
    (
        select * from (
    select row_number() over(partition by codename order by codename, timestamp desc) row_id, codename, price as latestPrice, discount as latestDis, timestamp as latestTime from 
        (
        select codename, discount, timestamp , min(price) as price from prices 
        group by codename, discount, timestamp
        )T
        ) T1 
        where row_id = 1
    )t_Latest
    ON T_Low.codename= T_Latest.codename and T_Low.row_id = T_Latest.row_id
)T
order by codename
```

Comment: It might help if you explained why your answer works when the original doesn't

Comment: In original query Id  field is used in query, while you want to perform grouping then such fields like ID which is always unique must be skipped. Unnecessarily join is there in query. See I have updated answer it works for the desired output.

Comment: Earlier answer was not checked by me just based on assumption, I have tested this you can check it now.

Comment: Thanks Emipro. Though I only want to be performing the aggregate functions on price (for getting the MIN(price)) and timestamp (for getting the MAX(timestamp). I want the discount from whatever row it finds to have the lowest price and latest timestamp.

Comment: Your example above is close, but it gets the min(price) as well as the min(discount). In reality, an item with the smallest discount would not have the lowest price.

Comment: EDIT: Have updated the original question to help better explain what I am aiming for

Answer (score 0):

So after some playing with joins I was able to get the 2 queries to output onto a single row per codename:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT p.* 
  FROM prices p
  JOIN 
  ( 
    SELECT codename, MIN(price) minPrice
    FROM prices GROUP BY codename
  ) p2
  ON p.price = p2.minPrice AND p.codename = p2.codename
) min
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT p.* 
  FROM prices p
  JOIN 
  ( 
    SELECT codename, MAX(timestamp) maxTime
    FROM prices GROUP BY codename
  ) p2
  ON p.timestamp = p2.maxTime AND p.codename = p2.codename
) latest
ON latest.codename = min.codename
```

I'm sure the query is far from perfect, but it does give me the results I am looking for.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc042/2)

If there is anything drastically wrong with this, please let me know and I can update.